# Git pre-commit hook not adding file on Windows

Tags: windows, git, githooks, tortoisegit

I have a pre-commit hook that's running a mysqldump to keep track of MySQL.
I'm trying to add that dump to the commit, but for some reasons it won't.

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -f database.sql

exec "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" --skip-comments -u root --password=password my-database > database.sql

git add database.sql
```

The file is created, but not added to the commit. 
Running TortoiseGit on Windows 7.

Comment: Is the file created in the correct directory?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, but here a step by step guide, how it works on my windows 10 machine with xampplite.

1. go to your project git
2. go to "hooks\"
3. create file "pre-commit" (without file ending)
4. go to file properties and give full access to windows user
5. open pre-commit and paste:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> "C:\xampplite\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u dbuser -ppassword
>   database_name > database_name.sql
>
> git add database_name.sql exit 0

(-u username -ppassword databasename > file.sql)

file will be stored in project root. between -p and password is NO space.

Now, before every commit a mysql dump will be done and added to the commit.